Proving that if $a < \frac{1}{a} < \frac{1}{b} < b$, then $a < - 1$, for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a, b \neq 0$
I'm proving the following statment from Daniel Velleman's How to Prove It:

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers. Prove that if $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < -1$.

Following a hint given by the author, I've proceeded as follows: let us first prove $a < 0$. Assume $a > 0$. Then multiplying $a < \frac{1}{a}$ by $a$ gives $a^2 < 1$, i.e. $\vert a \vert < 1$. But this contradicts the assumption that $a < \frac{1}{a}$, hence $a < 0$. Hence multiplying $a < \frac{1}{a}$ by $a$ gives $a^2 > 1$, i.e. $a < -1$ or $a > 1$. Since $a < 0$, we conclude $a < -1$. $\square$
I think this proof is correct, but does this mean that the second part of the inequality involving $b$ is redundant?
Edited and corrected proof
Let us first prove $a < 0$. Assume $a > 0$. Then we can distinguish the following three cases:

$a > 1$. But this contradicts the assumption that $a < \frac{1}{a}$, so it is false;
$a = 1$. But this contradicts the assumption that $a < \frac{1}{a}$, so it is false;
$0 < a < 1$. Then $\frac{1}{a} > 1$. Also, since $b > a$ and hence $b > 0$, $b < \frac{1}{b}$ implies $b < 1$. But this contradicts the assumption that $\frac{1}{a} < b$, so $0 < a < 1$ is false.

Hence $a < 0$. So multiplying $a < \frac{1}{a}$ by $a$ gives $a^2 > 1$, i.e. $a < -1$ or $a > 1$. Since $a < 0$, we conclude $a < -1$. $\square$
I think this is correct now?

" |a|<1. But this contradicts the assumption that $a<\frac 1a$"   It does no such thing.  If $0 < a < 1$ then $\frac 1a > 1 > a$ and there is absolutely no contradiction at all.

The easiest way to attack the problem is to first identify all $~x~$ such that $~x < (1/x).~$  Note that $~x~$ may be positive or negative.

Here's the thing.  $a < \frac 1a$ is not a contradiction.  But if $a > 0$ then either 1) $a > 1$ and $\frac 1a < 1 < a$.  or 2) $a=1$ and $\frac 1a = 1 =\frac 1a$ or 3) $0 < a <1$ and $\frac 1a > 1 > a > 0$.   So if $a < \frac 1a$ then either $\alpha$) $0 < a < 1$ or $\beta$) $a<0$.  ... But the same thing is true for $b$.  So if you have $0 < a < 1 < \frac 1a < \frac 1b$ we have no contradiction.  But $1 < \frac 1b \implies b < 1$ and so $1 < \frac 1b < b$ would be.

I have to admit to being curious.  Why do you think $|a| < 1$ contradicts $a < \frac 1a$? I don't see that at all.  In fact $0< a < 1$ ASSURES that $a < \frac 1a$.

@fleablood Sorry, that is indeed an error in my proof. In your reply, the conclusion that $b < 1$ contradicts the assumption that $ \frac{1}{a} < b$, right?

There's so many more than one way to do it. Note: that $x$ and $\frac1x$ always have the same sign (do you see why). Notice that if we are talking about postive numbers we have $a<b\iff\frac1b< \frac1a$.  Note that if $a>0$ then we have $0<a<\frac 1a<\frac 1b <b$ so we have both $a<b$ and $\frac 1a < \frac 1b$.  Also we can multiply everything by $a, b$ or $ab$ and what happens? Also note $1$ or $-1$ must be between $x$ and $\frac 1x$ (do you see why). With those in mind there are about 300 different ways we can do the proof and they are all good. Do the one that reaches out to you.
